# Show that if for every sequence $(x_{n})$ converging to zero, $(f(x_n))$ is limited, then $f$ is a limited functional

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $\mathbb{X}$ a normed vector space. If $f\colon \mathbb{X}\to\mathbb{K}$ is a linear functional such that for all sequence $(x_{n})$ that converges to zero we have that $(f(x_{n}))$ is bounded. Show that $f$ is a bounded functional. Could someone help me, please? I was unable to come up with ideas for this exercise.

Comment: I suspect you mean bounded rather than limited?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let assume by contradiction that a functional like that can be unbounded, then $\exists(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ a bounded sequence of elements of $\mathbb{X}$ such that $(f(x_n))_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is unbounded (we can assume $\lim_{n\to+\infty}|f(x_n)|=+\infty$, if it is not strictly true just consider a subsequence of $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ with this proprierty and rename that $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$), let now consider $(y_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $y_n=\frac{x_n}{\sqrt{1+|f(x_n)|}}\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$. Now, $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is buonded and $(f(x_n))_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ goes to $+\infty$, so $(y_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is infinitesimal and $f(y_n)=\frac{f(x_n)}{\sqrt{1+|f(x_n)|}}$, so $\lim_{n\to+\infty}|f(y_n)|=+\infty$, contradiction.